# switch from Datepicker to user input

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm developping a chatbot. At some point, I ask the user to pick a date, I use the following code in the client side :

```
var elems = document.querySelector(".usrInput");
var currYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
var options = {
    defaultDate: new Date(currYear-1,1,31),
    maxDate: new Date(currYear+1,12,31),
    yearRange: [currYear-1, currYear+1],
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd"
    };

var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
```

I want to restore the initial behavior of the element .usrInput after the date is picked, to allow the used to continue the conversation. Below is a minimal example of the html.

```
     <html>
        <head>
          <title>chatbot</title>
          <!--Import materialize.css-->
            <link
            rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="static/css/materialize.min.css"/>
         </head>
        <body>
         <div class="container">
          <div class="widget">
            <div class="chat_header">
              <span class="chat_header_title">Chatbot name</span>
            <!--Chatbot contents goes here -->
            <div class="chats" id="chats">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="keypad">
              <textarea
                id="userInput"
                placeholder="Type something..."
                class="usrInput"
              ></textarea>
              <div id="sendButton">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I'm new to both materialize and js. Thanks.

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the HTML too?

Comment: I just edited the post, thank you.

Comment: Looking at [their documentation](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) you could use `instances[indexOfTheElement].destroy();`?

Comment: instances["userInput"].destroy(); doesn't change anything

Comment: I would assume `indexOfTheElement` should be a number not an ID. Please may you share the output of `console.log(instances)`?